# How to convert this complex logic indicator in pinescript to python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pine-script, pine-script-v5

Details of my query:

1. I'm trying to make an automated trading bot (personal use).
2. I found this indicator on TradingView to be quite accurate. Unfortunately it is not a strategy, so I cannot automate trades using pre-built interfaces. It is called kNN Machine Learning by Capissimo on TradingView, so you guys can check it out for reference. (code below)
3. I decided to use my python knowledge to build a bot myself. (code below as well)
4. How do I convert this logic to python? And I'm also not sure how to execute the code to have it make the trades continuously on Binance.
5. I've written the logic, and have it output on a sample chart using the Binance API, but it doesn't seem to be very accurate. (also code below)
6. I've written it on Visual Studio Code.

Pinescript kNN indicator Code:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © capissimo

//@version=5
indicator('Machine Learning: kNN-based Strategy', 'ML-kNN', true, max_labels_count=300, format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

// kNN-based Strategy (FX and Crypto)
// Description: 
// This strategy uses a classic machine learning algorithm - k Nearest Neighbours (kNN) - 
// to let you find a prediction for the next (tomorrow's, next month's, etc.) market move. 
// Being an unsupervised machine learning algorithm, kNN is one of the most simple learning algorithms. 

// To do a prediction of the next market move, the kNN algorithm uses the historic data, 
// collected in 3 arrays - feature1, feature2 and directions, - and finds the k-nearest 
// neighbours of the current indicator(s) values. 

// The two dimensional kNN algorithm just has a look on what has happened in the past when 
// the two indicators had a similar level. It then looks at the k nearest neighbours, 
// sees their state and thus classifies the current point.

// The kNN algorithm offers a framework to test all kinds of indicators easily to see if they 
// have got any *predictive value*. One can easily add cog, wpr and others.
// Note: TradingViews's playback feature helps to see this strategy in action.
// Warning: Signals ARE repainting.

// Style tags: Trend Following, Trend Analysis
// Asset class: Equities, Futures, ETFs, Currencies and Commodities
// Dataset: FX Minutes/Hours+++/Days

//-- Preset Dates

int startdate = timestamp('01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT+10')
int stopdate  = timestamp('31 Dec 2025 23:45:00 GMT+10')

//-- Inputs

StartDate  = input.time  (startdate, 'Start Date')
StopDate   = input.time  (stopdate,  'Stop Date')
Indicator  = input.string('All',     'Indicator',   ['RSI','ROC','CCI','Volume','All'])
ShortWinow = input.int   (14,        'Short Period [1..n]', 1)
LongWindow = input.int   (28,        'Long Period [2..n]',  2)
BaseK      = input.int   (252,       'Base No. of Neighbours (K) [5..n]', 5)
Filter     = input.bool  (false,     'Volatility Filter')
Bars       = input.int   (300,       'Bar Threshold [2..5000]', 2, 5000)

//-- Constants

var int BUY   = 1
var int SELL  =-1
var int CLEAR = 0

var int k     = math.floor(math.sqrt(BaseK))  // k Value for kNN algo

//-- Variable

// Training data, normalized to the range of [0,...,100]
var array<float> feature1   = array.new_float(0)  // [0,...,100]
var array<float> feature2   = array.new_float(0)  //    ...
var array<int>   directions = array.new_int(0)    // [-1; +1]

// Result data
var array<int>   predictions = array.new_int(0)
var float        prediction  = 0.0
var array<int>   bars        = array.new<int>(1, 0) // array used as a container for inter-bar variables

// Signals
var int          signal      = CLEAR

//-- Functions

minimax(float x, int p, float min, float max) => 
    float hi = ta.highest(x, p), float lo = ta.lowest(x, p)
    (max - min) * (x - lo)/(hi - lo) + min

cAqua(int g) => g>9?#0080FFff:g>8?#0080FFe5:g>7?#0080FFcc:g>6?#0080FFb2:g>5?#0080FF99:g>4?#0080FF7f:g>3?#0080FF66:g>2?#0080FF4c:g>1?#0080FF33:#00C0FF19
cPink(int g) => g>9?#FF0080ff:g>8?#FF0080e5:g>7?#FF0080cc:g>6?#FF0080b2:g>5?#FF008099:g>4?#FF00807f:g>3?#FF008066:g>2?#FF00804c:g>1?#FF008033:#FF008019

inside_window(float start, float stop) =>  
    time >= start and time <= stop ? true : false

//-- Logic

bool window = inside_window(StartDate, StopDate)

// 3 pairs of predictor indicators, long and short each
float rs = ta.rsi(close,   LongWindow),        float rf = ta.rsi(close,   ShortWinow)
float cs = ta.cci(close,   LongWindow),        float cf = ta.cci(close,   ShortWinow)
float os = ta.roc(close,   LongWindow),        float of = ta.roc(close,   ShortWinow)
float vs = minimax(volume, LongWindow, 0, 99), float vf = minimax(volume, ShortWinow, 0, 99)

// TOADD or TOTRYOUT:
//    ta.cmo(close, LongWindow), ta.cmo(close, ShortWinow)
//    ta.mfi(close, LongWindow), ta.mfi(close, ShortWinow)
//    ta.mom(close, LongWindow), ta.mom(close, ShortWinow)

float f1 = switch Indicator
    'RSI'    => rs 
    'CCI'    => cs 
    'ROC'    => os 
    'Volume' => vs 
    => math.avg(rs, cs, os, vs)

float f2 = switch Indicator
    'RSI'    => rf 
    'CCI'    => cf
    'ROC'    => of
    'Volume' => vf 
    => math.avg(rf, cf, of, vf)

// Classification data, what happens on the next bar
int class_label = int(math.sign(close[1] - close[0])) // eq. close[1]<close[0] ? SELL: close[1]>close[0] ? BUY : CLEAR

// Use particular training period
if window
    // Store everything in arrays. Features represent a square 100 x 100 matrix,
    // whose row-colum intersections represent class labels, showing historic directions
    array.push(feature1, f1)
    array.push(feature2, f2)
    array.push(directions, class_label)

// Ucomment the followng statement (if barstate.islast) and tab everything below
// between BOBlock and EOBlock marks to see just the recent several signals gradually 
// showing up, rather than all the preceding signals

//if barstate.islast   

//==BOBlock 

// Core logic of the algorithm
int   size    = array.size(directions)
float maxdist = -999.0
// Loop through the training arrays, getting distances and corresponding directions.
for i=0 to size-1
    // Calculate the euclidean distance of current point to all historic points,
    // here the metric used might as well be a manhattan distance or any other.
    float d = math.sqrt(math.pow(f1 - array.get(feature1, i), 2) + math.pow(f2 - array.get(feature2, i), 2))
    
    if d > maxdist
        maxdist := d
        if array.size(predictions) >= k
            array.shift(predictions)
        array.push(predictions, array.get(directions, i))
        
//==EOBlock 

// Note: in this setup there's no need for distances array (i.e. array.push(distances, d)),
//       but the drawback is that a sudden max value may shadow all the subsequent values.
// One of the ways to bypass this is to:
// 1) store d in distances array,
// 2) calculate newdirs = bubbleSort(distances, directions), and then 
// 3) take a slice with array.slice(newdirs) from the end
        
// Get the overall prediction of k nearest neighbours
prediction := array.sum(predictions)   

bool filter = Filter ? ta.atr(10) > ta.atr(40) : true // filter out by volatility or ex. ta.atr(1) > ta.atr(10)...

// Now that we got a prediction for the next market move, we need to make use of this prediction and 
// trade it. The returns then will show if everything works as predicted.
// Over here is a simple long/short interpretation of the prediction, 
// but of course one could also use the quality of the prediction (+5 or +1) in some sort of way,
// ex. for position sizing.

bool long  = prediction > 0 and filter
bool short = prediction < 0 and filter
bool clear = not(long and short)

if array.get(bars, 0)==Bars    // stop by trade duration
    signal := CLEAR
    array.set(bars, 0, 0)
else
    array.set(bars, 0, array.get(bars, 0) + 1)

signal := long ? BUY : short ? SELL : clear ? CLEAR : nz(signal[1])

int  changed         = ta.change(signal)
bool startLongTrade  = changed and signal==BUY 
bool startShortTrade = changed and signal==SELL 
// bool endLongTrade    = changed and signal==SELL
// bool endShortTrade   = changed and signal==BUY  
bool clear_condition = changed and signal==CLEAR //or (changed and signal==SELL) or (changed and signal==BUY)

float maxpos = ta.highest(high, 10)
float minpos = ta.lowest (low,  10)

//-- Visuals

plotshape(startLongTrade  ? minpos : na, 'Buy',      shape.labelup,   location.belowbar, cAqua(int(prediction*5)),  size=size.small)  // color intensity correction
plotshape(startShortTrade ? maxpos : na, 'Sell',     shape.labeldown, location.abovebar, cPink(int(-prediction*5)), size=size.small)
// plot(endLongTrade         ? ohlc4  : na, 'StopBuy',  cAqua(6), 3, plot.style_cross)
// plot(endShortTrade        ? ohlc4  : na, 'StopSell', cPink(6), 3, plot.style_cross)
plot(clear_condition      ? close  : na, 'ClearPos', color.yellow, 4, plot.style_cross)


//-- Notification

// if changed and signal==BUY 
//     alert('Buy Alert', alert.freq_once_per_bar)  // alert.freq_once_per_bar_close
// if changed and signal==SELL 
//     alert('Sell Alert', alert.freq_once_per_bar)

alertcondition(startLongTrade,  'Buy',  'Go long!')
alertcondition(startShortTrade, 'Sell', 'Go short!') 
//alertcondition(startLongTrade or startShortTrade, 'Alert', 'Deal Time!')

//-------------------- Backtesting (TODO)

// show_cumtr = input.bool (false, 'Show Trade Return?')
// lot_size   = input.float(100.0, 'Lot Size', [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,1,2,3,5,10,20,30,50,100,1000,2000,3000,5000,10000]) 

// var start_lt     = 0.  
// var long_trades  = 0.
// var start_st     = 0.  
// var short_trades = 0.

// if startLongTrade 
//     start_lt := ohlc4 
// if endLongTrade
//     long_trades := (open - start_lt) * lot_size  
// if startShortTrade 
//     start_st := ohlc4 
// if endShortTrade
//     short_trades := (start_st - open) * lot_size 
    
// cumreturn = ta.cum(long_trades) + ta.cum(short_trades) 
    
// var label lbl = na
// if show_cumtr //and barstate.islast  
//     lbl := label.new(bar_index+10, close, 'CumReturn: ' + str.tostring(cumreturn, '#.#'), xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, 
//                      color.new(color.blue, 100), label.style_label_left, color.black, size.small, text.align_left)
//     label.delete(lbl[1])
```

Code in which I have attempted to decode the logic and output it on a sample live-time chart.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Step 1: Define the necessary libraries and variables

symbol = 'BTCUSDT'  # Example trading pair
interval = '1d'    # Example time interval (daily)
limit = 1000       # Number of historical data points to retrieve

# Step 2: Make a request to the Binance API to fetch historical data

url = f"https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol={symbol}&interval={interval}&limit={limit}"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

# Step 3: Parse the API response into a pandas DataFrame and extract the necessary columns

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'close_time', 'quote_asset_volume',
                                 'number_of_trades', 'taker_buy_base_asset_volume', 'taker_buy_quote_asset_volume', 'ignore'])
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
df['close'] = pd.to_numeric(df['close'])

# Step 4: Apply the trading algorithm to generate entry and exit signals based on the historical data

# Example trading algorithm based on provided code
df['signal'] = 0  # Initialize the signal column

short_window = 14
long_window = 28

for i in range(long_window, len(df)):
    short_avg = df['close'].iloc[i - short_window:i].mean()
    long_avg = df['close'].iloc[i - long_window:i].mean()

    if short_avg > long_avg:
        df.loc[i, 'signal'] = 1  # Entry signal
    elif short_avg < long_avg:
        df.loc[i, 'signal'] = -1  # Exit signal

# Step 5: Create a line chart to visualize the historical data with entry and exit signals

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(df['timestamp'], df['close'], color='blue', linewidth=1, label='Close')

# Plot entry and exit signals
entry_signals = df[df['signal'] == 1]
exit_signals = df[df['signal'] == -1]
plt.scatter(entry_signals['timestamp'], entry_signals['close'], color='green', marker='^', label='Entry')
plt.scatter(exit_signals['timestamp'], exit_signals['close'], color='red', marker='v', label='Exit')

plt.xlabel('Timestamp')
plt.ylabel('Close Price')
plt.title('Trading Algorithm Entries and Exits')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Code for the sample trading bot I've written.

```
import ccxt
import numpy as np
import talib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set up Binance API credentials
api_key = 'your_api_key'
secret_key = 'your_secret_key'

# Create an instance of the Binance exchange class
exchange = ccxt.binance({
    'apiKey': api_key,
    'secret': secret_key,
    'enableRateLimit': True,
})

# Define variables and parameters
symbol = 'BTC/USDT'  # Replace with the desired trading pair
timeframe = '1h'  # Replace with the desired timeframe
start_date = '2021-01-01'  # Replace with the desired start date

short_window = 14  # Short period for indicators
long_window = 28  # Long period for indicators
base_k = 252  # Base number of neighbors (K) for kNN algorithm
filter_volatility = False  # Enable or disable volatility filter
bar_threshold = 300  # Bar threshold for trade duration

# Fetch historical OHLCV data from the Binance API
ohlcvs = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(symbol, timeframe, exchange.parse8601(start_date))
timestamps = np.array([ohlc[0] for ohlc in ohlcvs])
opens = np.array([ohlc[1] for ohlc in ohlcvs])
highs = np.array([ohlc[2] for ohlc in ohlcvs])
lows = np.array([ohlc[3] for ohlc in ohlcvs])
closes = np.array([ohlc[4] for ohlc in ohlcvs])
volumes = np.array([ohlc[5] for ohlc in ohlcvs])

# Calculate technical indicators
rsi = talib.RSI(closes, timeperiod=long_window)
cci = talib.CCI(highs, lows, closes, timeperiod=long_window)
roc = talib.ROC(closes, timeperiod=long_window)
volume_scaled = (volumes - np.min(volumes)) / (np.max(volumes) - np.min(volumes)) * 100

# kNN-based algorithm
def kNN_algorithm(feature1, feature2, directions, f1, f2, k):
    distances = np.sqrt(np.power(f1 - feature1, 2) + np.power(f2 - feature2, 2))
    indices = np.argsort(distances)
    k_nearest = directions[indices[:k]]
    prediction = np.sign(np.sum(k_nearest))
    return prediction

predictions = []
for i in range(len(timestamps)):
    if i >= base_k:
        f1 = np.mean(rsi[i - base_k + 1:i + 1])
        f2 = np.mean(cci[i - base_k + 1:i + 1])
        direction = np.sign(closes[i] - closes[i - 1])
        predictions.append(kNN_algorithm(rsi[:i], cci[:i], direction[:i], f1, f2, int(np.sqrt(base_k))))
    else:
        predictions.append(0)

# Plot the OHLCV chart and overlay buy and sell signals
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.title(f'{symbol} {timeframe} Chart')
plt.plot(timestamps, closes, label='Close')

buys = np.where(np.array(predictions) > 0)[0]
sells = np.where(np.array(predictions) < 0)[0]

plt.scatter(timestamps[buys], closes[buys], color='green', marker='^', label='Buy')
plt.scatter(timestamps[sells], closes[sells], color='red', marker='v', label='Sell')

plt.xlabel('Timestamp')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Would appreciate any and all help I can get on this. I'm self-taught, and have done a lot of back and forth on the internet including chat-GPT to get this much done. However, no concrete solution. Thank you so much for reading till here if you have!